# How to find users now that the "Users" tab is gone?

Tags: discussion

Today I ran across an interesting user name and wanted to find out if there is more than one user with this specific nickname.

But somehow with the new design of the Stack Overflow page, I am unable to find the "Users" tab (like it is shown in [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82768/how-to-find-users-by-name)) or a search field for typing in the nickname.  All I can see today is a "Top users" tab but this does not contain any search option like the old "Filter by User".

[image]

I finally stumbled across a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/users) to the seemingly inaccessible page and was very happy to find it still functional.

But I think it's a pity that the search option seems to be a hidden feature today.

Other use cases where the search option was helpful (if the nickname was not "Sam"; luckily many users prefer a rather unique nickname):

- quickly finding a useful answer if only one could remember part of the author's nickname
- finding out how many others share your chosen nickname - maybe even before really using that nickname
- just wanting to know if a certain user is still active

Did I miss something and the search option is not gone after all?
And if it is, does it have to stay that way?

Comment: enable keyboard shortcuts, then press g followed by u. Otherwise, it's in that little hamburger menu in the top left.

Comment: The link to the users page is in the sidebar, which is hidden behind the burger in the top left in your case.

Comment: @Kevin B - thanks, I was looking for something like the hamburger menu because not everyone will have keyboard shortcuts enabled. If you post your suggestion as an answer then I'll be happy to accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Users page, Tags page, and new Questions page are all in the left sidebar. You naturally turned that off, so they're now in the top-left hamburger menu.

Comment: Just curious but any reason you made this cw?

Comment: Somehow I managed to ignore the hamburger icon while searching. Many thanks  to you and to everyone else who pointed me in the right direction :)